# get data from database into textfield in cordova iphone

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, cordova-3

I'm working with database in cordova for ios..I've successfully insert,select and delete the data.I'm inserting FirstName,LastName and addresses.when i get data from the database at that time i append into main div...

```
    $('#maindiv').append('<div name ="DivTitle" id="'+results.rows.item(i).id+' " 
onclick="Titleclicked(this.id);" ><label id="Title"  >'+results.rows.item(i).FirstName+'</label><label id="Description" style="display:block;text-indent:2px;font-size:13px;color: black;font-family: Comic Sans MS;">'+results.rows.item(i).LastName+'</label></div> ');
```

> function Titleclicked(id){
>
> ```
> alert("Titleclicked:::"+id);
> ```
>
> }

using this function,i can get id of data..Now,what  i want to do is when i clicked on div the page will navigate into add contact page.and i want to display data from the database  into name textfiled,lastname textfield and address textfield for update.....

Answer (score 2):

By using Titleclicked you getting the ID Now you use that id and invoke the query in backend
Select * from tablename where id=?;
 By using this Query you will get only one result set
    ("#textFirstnameId").val(results.rows.item(i).FirstName)          ("#textLastNameId").val(results.rows.item(i).LastName)

hope it's work